# try/catch, catch doesn't respond

Tags: java

this method must check if there is numbers in string/otherwise it should text in console"not a number"
 but it doesn't; help me to check it out pls!

```
public static int[] findNumbers(String text){
    String[]str=text.split(" ");
    int count =0;
    for (String s:str){
        if (isNumeric(s)) count++;
    }

    int[] numbers= new int[count];

    int index=0;
    try {
        for (String s:str){
            if (isNumeric(s)) numbers[index]=Integer.parseInt(s);
        }
        return numbers;

    }catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println("not a number");
    }
    return numbers;
}

private static boolean isNumeric(String text){
    if (text==null) return false;
    char[] chars=text.toCharArray();
    for (char ch:chars){
        if (!Character.isDigit(ch)) return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

}

Comment: You're only calling `parseInt` if the string is numeric, and if it's numeric, `parseInt` presumably won't cause an error to be thrown.

Comment: try and catch is for error handling.  I think you're going to want an if statement here.  Your try catch executes with valid code and if it doesn't, for whatever reason you'd catch it with a 'general exception'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this implementation which avoids implementing `isNumeric` yourself and returns a list instead of an array because the length of the `numbers` is not fixed

```java
List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>();
for (String s : str) {
    try {
         numbers.add(Integer.valueOf(s));
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
         System.out.println(s + " not a number");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Add an else to isNumeric:

```
if (isNumeric(s)) {
    numbers[index]=Integer.parseInt(s);
} else {
    System.out.println("not a number");
}
```

Change the error message inside the catch. It might still be called, like when the string is to big to be an Integer.

Answer (score 1):

You can reduce your code as follows:

```
public static List<Integer> findNumbers(String text) {
    String[] str = text.split(" ");
    List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (String s : str) {
        try {
            numbers.add(Integer.parseInt(s));
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            System.out.println(s+" is not an integer");
        }
    }
    return numbers;
}
```